# why is additional space added when line breaks?

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/lalablah/4uybxdko/101/

```
<div class="container">
  <span>
    this is some longlonglonglonglonglong text
  </span>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}

.indicator {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I have a flex container set to fixed width and has two items in it.

The first item has a long text and will line-break.

I expected that there wouldn't be any space between flex items but there is.

what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't get if, can you show us screenshot with that space?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any space between the flex items. You could see this if you applied a a background colour to each of them.

There is space between the last letter of the first line and the edge of the span it is in.

This is because word-wrapping happens between words, not at the exact edge of the container (i.e. it isn't going to split a letter in half to make the line fit perfectly into the space).

(See also `text-align: justify`, the default is `start`)

Comment: thanks, is there any way to get rid of that extra space in the span?

Comment: I refer you to the last line of this answer.